# nohup C++ fstream

Tags: c++, linux, g++, fstream, nohup

When i compile the following C++ code with g++ under Linuxit works fine, however when i try to run

```
nohup ./a.out &
```

it stops immediately with info

```
[7]+  Stopped                 nohup ./a.out
```

the source code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    ofstream file("hm.txt",ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
    file << "123";
    file.close();

return 0;
}
```

Can you point out my mistake?

Comment: When i try to execute ./a.out everything works fine.

Comment: My apologies, i was not clear enough, when invoked with nohup, it stops immediately without creating any file.

Comment: As far as I know it should print: `[1]+  Done                    nohup ./a.out`. This is how it works on my PC. I'm not sure where `Stopped` comes from.

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/nohup` instead...

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I've just tried both of the following versions with no effect: _/usr/bin/nohup /home/me/cpp/a.out &_ and _/usr/bin/nohup ./a.out &_

Comment: You could investigate further into "stops immediately": try writing something to `cerr`; do some error checking on the file object; etc.  If you add some I/O to `cerr` or `cout`, be sure to look for the output in the `nohup` file since `nohup` will redirect your terminal I/O.

Comment: What happens if you run `jobs` or `bg` or `fg`?

Comment: Adding _cout<<"hello";_ as the first line after _main(){_ and invoking  _nohup ./a.out &_ didn't create file hm.txt and produced empty nohup.out.

Comment: Something else to try: `/usr/bin/nohup ./a.out </dev/zero`

Comment: Thank you @nobar, I'm not an experienced Linux user and i didn't know about `jobs`, `bg`, `fg` and to be honest i don't know how should i interpret the output. `Jobs` gave me bunch of lines like `[1]   Stopped                 nohup ./a.out`, `[2]   Stopped                 nohup ./a.out` and so on. `bg` gave me only one line `[9]+ nohup ./a.out &` and `fg` gave me only one line `nohup ./a.out`

Comment: Solved, but i don't understand why. Writing `/usr/bin/nohup ./a.out </dev/zero` did solve the problem, but then i have noticed that invoking `nohup ./a.out` without the `&` at the end worked fine. Thank  you @nobar, can you perhaps explain what difference does it make to put `&` in the end?

Comment: Did you also try: `/usr/bin/nohup ./a.out </dev/zero &` -- with both the `</dev/zero` *and* the `&`?

Comment: Yes and it gave me the same error, it looks like the problem is not with `nohup` but rather `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get it at first, but it seems like your system is deciding to put the program into a suspended (`Stopped` state).  `jobs` shows you all of the jobs stopped or running in the current terminal session.  `bg`/`fg` can be used to restart stopped jobs, so you might check to see if that caused the files to be written.  Another idea for further probing the cause is to run `/usr/bin/nohup strace ./a.out 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`.  The `strace` should dump all of the system calls to `stderr.txt` -- so you might be able to see an indication as to why it stopped.

It appears like a common cause for this type of problem is that the program wants some input and since (with `nohup`) there is no terminal to provide it, the system stops your program.  My first suggestion was to try the following in order to provide some auto-generated input:

```
/usr/bin/nohup ./a.out </dev/zero
```

On my system, it automatically runs it with this instead:

```
/usr/bin/nohup ./a.out </dev/null
```

I don't know why your system wouldn't automatically be providing a null input, and I also don't know why your program would be waiting for input.  Your original attempt worked fine for me (I can't reproduce your problem).

When I run `nohup ./a.out` (or `nohup ./a.out &`), I get the following message, which indicates the automatic input suppression:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

So another line of investigation is: why don't you see this message?

---

Another line of attack, since it seems like your system just doesn't like `nohup` with `&` is to restart the `Stopped` program as a background task with something like the following:

```
/usr/bin/nohup ./a.out & bg
```

Clearly, `nohup` is meant to be used with `&`, so your problem is a bit strange.